# J-1 visa usa duration and possibility to leave usa?

Tags: usa, visa, j-visa

With a J-1 visa is it possible to leave the US and re-enter?
Moreover, when you apply for a J visa do you have to specify the exact period of your stay in the US?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> With a J-1 visa is it possible to leave the US and re-enter?

Yes, as long as your visa remains valid.  J-1 visas are issued as multiple-entry visas.

> Moreover, when you apply for a J visa do you have to specify the exact period of your stay in the US?

You will apply for your J visa [after you have been accepted to a specific exchange visitor program](https://travel.state.gov/content/travel/en/us-visas/study/exchange.html), so your anticipated duration of stay will be known before you apply.

But the validity of the visa has no bearing on how long you can stay in the US.  The visa is only for entering the US; your allowed period of stay runs from 30 days before the start of your program until 30 days after it ends.